# Comparison of methods in a paper with a table

Tags: publications, tables

In my current paper I describe two methods for solving a problem in different ways. Both have advantages and disadvantages.
At the end of the paper I would like to compare the two methodologies with a table. So far it looks something like this:

```
 -------------------------------------------------
|           |     Method 1     |     Method 2    |
--------------------------------------------------
|Critera 1: |    very good     |       good      |
|Critera 2: | satisfactorily   |     very good   |
|Critera 3: |    very good     |       good      |
--------------------------------------------------
```

How would you manage that? Is such a table scientifically accepted?

Comment: Btw it's criterion (singular) or criteria (plural); and "satisfactorily" is an adverb, you probably mean "satisfactory", the adjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your paper describes the two methods in details (including the reasons why criterion X with method Y is assigned level Z in the table), I'd say yes, it makes perfect sense to provide this kind of table as a synthesis at the end of the paper. I would suggest adding cross-references in each cell, so that the reader can go see the details in the appropriate section for each case, e.g. "good (see §3.1)".

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues.

1. You'd need to establish methodology in any case.
2. Wouldn't you have hard numbers? For example,

   ```
                | Crab (1879) | Squarepants et al. (2017) | Squidward et al. (2018) | our method
   Criterion 1  | 1.89        | 2.45                      | 2.37                    | 2.5 
   Criterion 2  | 9.89        | 10.11                     | 5.55                    | 11.02 
   Criterion 3  | 33.3        | 44.44                     | 20.1                    | 49.8
   ```